# how to capture continuous Realtime progress stream of output (from ffmpeg)

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I am having trouble showing the progress of ffmpeg through my script. I compile my script to exe with ps2exe and ffmpeg output on standard error instead of outputting on standard out
So I used to pipe 1 option

my script.ps1 now is:

```
# $nb_of_frames= #some_int
& $ffmpeg_path -progress pipe:1 -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 25 -preset fast -an output.mp4
```

then I compile it with ps2exe. (to reproduce you don't need the compile, just use the above command with pipe:1 directly in cmd or PowerShell you will get the same behavior)

Normally with ffmpeg you get a progress reporting (that is interactive), one line containing the information and it keeps getting updated as 1 single line without spamming the console with 100s of lines, it looks like this.

```
frame= 7468 fps=115 q=22.0 size=   40704kB time=00:05:10.91 bitrate=1072.5kbits/s speed= 4.8x
```

But this does not appear in the compiled version of my script, so after digging I added `-progress pipe:1` to get the progress to appear on std out

Now I get a continuous output every second that looks like this:

```
frame=778
fps=310.36
stream_0_0_q=16.0
bitrate= 855.4kbits/s
total_size=3407872
progress=continue
...
frame=1092
fps=311.04
stream_0_0_q=19.0
bitrate= 699.5kbits/s
total_size=3932160
progress=continue
```

I would like to print some sort of updatable percentage out of this, I can compute a percentage easily if I can capture that frame number, but in this case, I don't know how to capture a real-time output like this and how to make my progress reporting update 1 single line of percentage in real-time (or some progress bar via symbols) instead of spamming on many lines

(or if there is a way to make the default progress of FFmpeg appear in the compiled version of my script that would work too)

edit: a suggestion based on the below answer

```
#use the following lines instead of write-progress if using with ps2exe
            #$a=($frame * 100 / $maxFrames)
            #$str = "#"*$a
            #$str2 = "-"*(100-$a)
            #Write-Host -NoNewLine "`r$a% complete | $str $str2|"
```

Thanks

Comment: Search for the output line that starts with `frame=`, split on `=` to extract frame number, calculate percentage and use `Write-Progress` to show a progress bar. Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: @zett42 `Search for the output line that starts with frame=, ` that part! You can't pipe input to write progress, nor to split. how exactly am I supposed to capture the output of ffmpeg in real time? so even if I use `ffmepg... | select-string "frame="`   where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how to capture current frame number from `ffmpeg` output, calculate percentage and pass it to `Write-Progress`:

```sh
$maxFrames = 12345

& $ffmpeg_path -progress pipe:1 -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 25 -preset fast -an output.mp4 |
    Select-String 'frame=(\d+)' | ForEach-Object {
        $frame = [int] $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value
        Write-Progress -Activity 'ffmpeg' -Status 'Converting' -PercentComplete ($frame * 100 / $maxFrames)
    }
```

**Remarks:**

- `Select-String` parameter is a regular expression that captures the frame number by the group `(\d+)` (where `\d` means a digit and `+` requires at least one digit). See this [Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/C2tO6b/1).
- `ForEach-Object` runs the given script block for each match of `Select-String`. Here `$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value` extracts the matched value from the first RegEx group. Then we convert it to integer to be able to use it for calculations.
- Finally calculate the percentage and pass it to `Write-Progress`.

Comment: this worked, thank you for explaining this, naively my thought was to pipe select string to write-progress which naturally did not work! Thanks a lot!

Comment: One thing to note, when using ps2exe to compile the script, it seems write-progress is not supported, I used your very exact same logic and just did a manual progress bar. I can not edit your answer to include this case because of the edit queue limit so I edited my question to put an example :), the manual progress bar may not seem exactly like wanted when running the ps1 script, but it works fine in the compiled .exe. (if needed one can use an `if ($PSScriptRoot) {run version with write-progress}else{run manual version}`